# NEXTJS Build will not evaluate server side ENV variable

Tags: firebase, next.js

I have a NEXTJS + Firebase app working fine with npm run dev on my laptop.  When I run `npm run build` for my app in a container I get the following error for my firebase private key which is in my .env.local file

```
74.82 ReferenceError: privateKey is not defined
```

Firebase admin file

```
privateKey = process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY || ""; 


if (!admin.apps.length && privateKey) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      privateKey: privateKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'), 
    })
  });
}
```

Dockerfile relevant part

```
# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

#copy the .env file to the root of the project
COPY ./.env.local ./.env.local
```

I can't seem to figure out why this env variable is not getting absorbed into the build process. I have client side variables in the same .env.local file that are loading into the app.